# How to run the chatbot when i use a LogicAdpater

Tags: chatbot

Why when i use a logicadapter I can not train my chatbot
(From Python3.6)?
Examples

```
bot = Chatbot("gol", logic_adapter=['chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter']) 
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer) 
bot.train("hey", "how are you")}
```